# How do I make searches on Mongodb using wildcard characters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

For example if my keyword is "all", I would like MongoDb to return all the documents in the given field containing the words "all" like "edgar allan poe" or "whitney hall". How do I do that in MongoDb? I've been stuck here for days so any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 17):

By using a regular expression. MongoDb has a [$regex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/) operator.

```
db.authors.find({name: {$regex: 'all', $options: 'i'}});
```

Regex operations cannot use indexes, so find() operations won't be efficient. An index can only be used for prefix(starts with) and case-sensitive matches like this query:

```
db.authors.find({name: {$regex: '^a'});
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this will not use indexes, so it's not going to scale very well at all.

Comment: It will use indexes for regex only if you search for beginning of a string: `^test`

Comment: This is missing a `}` at the end.
It should read `db.authors.find({name: {$regex: 'all', $options: 'i'}});`.